# Ubuntu 14.04 system requirements

Tags: 64-bit, system-requirements

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 installed in partition on my laptop. The configuration is:

- Pentium core 2 duo processor
- 3GB RAM
- Hard disk allocated for partition 15GB

It's an old dell inspiron 1525 laptop. I have 64 bit version installed but I feel I should have installed 32 bit one. Not sure how do I downgrade it.

Comment: You need to format the earlier Ubuntu and start with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04-32bit.

Comment: Is it? Then what if I keep it the same? Can I run into problems in future? I will be using the system for web development

Comment: No. There will be no problem in using 64bit version for any development work.

Comment: 64 bit has many advantages over 32 bit version. If your unity desktop is sluggish, that's because of the video card, it got nothing to do with the CPU. And you can't fix that with a 32 bit version. Try a liter desktop environment (Lubuntu, Xubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit should run OK on your hardware, so there is no point in reinstalling a 32-bit operating system on your Dell Inspiron 1525 laptop. For more information about system requirements see the accepted answer to [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar).